# runtime error in selecting k minimum elements from a array using modified quicksort

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, runtime-error, quicksort

I tried a modified quick sort algorithm to find the  k minimum numbers from a array.
But iam getting a runtime error.I think it might be because of segmentation fault.I have used rand() function to select the pivot element so it the program works efficiently during worst case too.

Pls help me

```
void swap(int &a,int &b){
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
int partition(int arr[],int low,int high){
    int left,right,pivot;
    int r=low+(rand()%(high-low+1));
    swap(arr[r],arr[low]);
    pivot=arr[low];
    left=low;
    right=high;
    /*very imp: dont confuse between low,high and left,right
    for traversing and swapping you need left and right*/
    while(left<right){
        while(arr[left]<=pivot)
                left++;
        while(arr[right]>pivot)
               right--;
       if(left<right)
               swap(arr[left],arr[right]);

    }
    arr[low]=arr[right];
    arr[right]=pivot;
    return right;

}
void quickselect(int arr[],int k){
    int low=0;
    int high=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)-1;
    int index=partition(arr,low,high);
    while(index!=k-1){
        if(index>k-1){
            high=index-1;
            index=partition(arr,low,high);

        }
        else{
            low=index+1;
            index=partition(arr,low,high);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
       cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
int main(){
    int arr[]={34,1,2,89,56,23};
    quickselect(arr,3);

}
```

Comment: you should check the boundaries of your array

Comment: Do you know where the error occurs? Have you single-stepped the program in a debugger? Also note that using `rand` to pick the pivot doesn't eliminate the worst case, but rather just makes it less likely to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `sizeof(arr)` in `quickselect()` not to return the array size but the pointer size and assuming 32bit that would set high to 0 which maybe causes your problem